# Which original LEGO videogames had sets based on them?

Tags: video-games

Which original LEGO videogames have related sets that were either included with the game or were introduced alongside it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this question I will be listing all original LEGO games that were **not** based on an existing franchise or theme. This means games like LEGO Loco and Rock Raiders are included, but Bionicle and LEGO Marvel Super Heroes aren't. As it turns out, only **nine** games had original sets or themes.

I've assembled this list by going through every LEGO game, and then comparing that against the sets released in the same year the game was released.

All images link to their respective bricklink pages.

If I miss something, feel free to correct me.

## LEGO Island (1997)

The US release included polybag set 2181 with a minifig of Infomaniac, the character that helps the player through the game.

[image: Infomaniac set 2181]

## LEGO Loco (1998)

Certain versions of the original release include set 2585: "Track Buggy with Station Master and Cool Kid". Both minifigs are characters in the game.

[image: Set 2585 handcar]

## LEGO Chess (1998)

This game included set 2586: "The Crazy LEGO King". Interestingly enough, it took LEGO another seven years to release their first full chess set, set 851499, but they never released a board featuring any of the characters from the videogame.

[image: Set 2586: the crazy lego king]

## LEGO Rock Raiders (1999)

LEGO Rock Raiders introduced the Rock Raiders theme which ran from June 1999 to December 2000. It had a total of sixteen sets.

[image][image][image]

## LEGO Stunt Rally (2000)

Several sets came out featuring Stunt Rally characters and cars, but for some reason LEGO called the theme just "Race". The later Racers theme also had a few sets that featured minifigs from Stunt Rally.

[image][image][image]

## LEGO Island 2 (2001)

The PC release of Island 2 included set 3925; a keychain of the brickster.

[image: brickster]

## LEGO Racers 2 (2001)

The release of Racers 2 kicked off the Racers theme that ran from 2001 all the way to 2012. The first subtheme of Racers was Xalax, which were featured in the videogame.

[image][image][image]

## LEGO Island Xtreme Stunts (2002)

Island Xtreme Stunts had its own theme with a total of 13 sets. Several of the sets feature Pepper and the Brickster, which both also appeared in Island 1 & 2.

[image][image][image]

## LEGO City Undercover (2013)

While based on the city theme, set 60007 "High Speed Chase" was released after the game and features the game's main character; Chase McCain.

[image]

---

### Footnotes:

- LEGO Friends, which released in 1998, is unrelated to the Friends theme that launched in 2012.